# passing local storage to contenscript

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage, content-script

I m developing a chrome extension and i want to know that , 
is there any way to pass whole **local storage** to **contentscript** from **background page** using

[message passing between content script and extension page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html)

so that i can use all key/value of local storage from content script ?

Answer (score 0):

send this from background page:

```
sendResponse({all_lS: JSON.stringify(localStorage));
```

in contentscript:

```
var lS =  JSON.parse(response.all_lS);
```

It will be copy of your localStorage.

Comment: it will be a copy so basically my local storage will have twice the size of required ?? means if i have 1 mb local storage then after using above statement local storage size will be 2 mb ?? Am i write or some thing else ??

Comment: `JSON.stringify(localStorage);` - this makes new string variable. It isn't localStorage. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)